# Unable to get __dirname value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `__dirname` to get absolute path to GraphQL schema:

```
const schema = loadSchemaSync(path.join(__dirname, './graphql/schemas/schema.graphql'), {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()]
});
```

I have changed module to fit ES6 module standard and `__dirname` now is undefined.
[image: __dirname]

How can I resolve path to schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue with `esm` + `__dirname`

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs

#### Differences between ES modules and CommonJS

#### No __filename or __dirname

These CommonJS variables are not available in ES modules.

__filename and __dirname use cases can be replicated via import.meta.url.

try to fix by this example
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta_url

```
loadSchemaSync(path.join(import.meta.url, './graphql/schemas/schema.graphql'), ...
```

Comment: Is this the only way to get path? ```import.meta.url``` corrupts path with cyrillic symbols: ```file:///C:/Users/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD/WebstormProjects/EDCM-API/src/app.mjs```

Comment: maybe built in ```decodeURI``` can solve this problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, but needed to replace ```file:///``` like that: ```decodeURI(import.meta.url).replace(/^file:\/\/\//, '');```